# How do I return error header if a db call throws an error?

Tags: node.js, express, couchbase

I have a small data gathering web app running with NodeJS and Couchbase. The requirement is, that when a 3rd party pushes some data to us and we are able to process it, we return the 200 header, but if there are any problems with storing that data, we return 500. This means that they can re-try with the failed data batch.

I'm having an issue where the 200 is always returned (because the DB calls are completed asynchronously). Here's an example:

```
...
var app = express();

function create(req, res) {

    var error = false;

    // Parse all the entries in request
    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
        var event = req.body[i];

        if (!event.email) {
            // log error to file
            error = true;
            res.send("Event object does not have an email address!", 500);
        }

        // Greate the id index value
        var event_id = 'blah';

        // See if record already exists
        db.get(event_id, function (err, result) {

            var doc = result.value;
            if (doc === undefined) {
                // Add a new record
                db.add(event_id, event, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        error = true;
                        res.send('There were processing errors', 500);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    if (error)
        res.send("Try again", 500);
    else
        res.send("OK", 200);
}
app.post('/create', create);
```

Is there a way of making the app wait for those DB calls to complete, i.e. for this funciton to be synchronous? Or am I using a wrong tech for this? :(

I decided to go with NodeJS+Couchbase because we are likely to have a very high amount of calls, where the data (small JSON objects) must be written, read and deleted. EDIT: Ah the data structure is likely to change for various events, so being able to store non-uniformly shaped documents its of a great advantage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical use case for the [`async` library](https://github.com/caolan/async), which is a utility-belt library with lots of patterns to work with asynchronous functions.

Since you need to call an asynchronous function for each record, you can use [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), which executes an asynchronous function for all elements of an array. A last callback is called when all asynchronous tasks are finished.

```
var app = express();

function handleEvent = function (event, callback) {
    if (! event.email) {
        callback(new Error('Event object does not have an email address!'));
    }
    var event_id = 'blah';
    db.get(event_id, function (err, result) {
        var doc = result.value;
        if (doc === undefined) {
            // Add a new record
            db.add(event_id, event, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(new Error('There were processing errors'));
                }
                else {
                    callback(null);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function create(req, res) {
    // https://github.com/caolan/async#each
    async.each(req.body, handleEvent, function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err.message, 500);
        else
            res.send('OK', 200);
    });
}
```

Comment: Aah, you give me hope :) I was actually considering reverting back to php... Thank you

Comment: Could be a silly question (I'm just learning node too) - but shouldn't we return callback? Or at least return after callback, to stop further execution of this function?

Comment: If you want to write good (read asynchronous) node.js app, in most cases your functions will not return anything. They (functions) will just call another functions - callbacks. This approach is commonly called "[Callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)". Here is a link to very useful [tutorial](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) for node begginers. It available in different languages, so I think it will be undestandable and easy to read. And answering your question - to stop function execution - write `return;` as soon as possible, if it's just simple call and you don't need to do after it.

Comment: `return` in asynchronous functions are often used to stop the function execution immediately (eg. in order not to write a big `if…else`), because nobody cares of the return value of an asynchronous function: when an async. function has a result, it just calls another function with the result.